# Stop flicker in Ubuntu when mouse travels back using synergy/Make xset -dpms permanent

Tags: linux, ubuntu, synergy, ubuntu-11.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04, now when my mouse travels back from my windows synergy client to the ubuntu synergy server, my Ubuntu monitor blacks out for a second or 2.

I know that `xset -dpms` will fix it for my session.

I've searched around for what is the most correct way to permanently fix this so that I don't have to run `xset -dpms` every time I re-start my Ubuntu machine.
The best I've come up with is to put `xset -dpms` in my Startup Applications, which seems to me like a kluge.

Anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have a line in the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf of the form:

Option: "DPMS"

in the monitor section.  If so, removing it may solve your problem.  I will update to confirm or refute this on my next reboot.

-pmr